# How can I use one django app ( with one db ) in two projects ? ( Using my app as a service )

Tags: python, django, soa

**The Problem ->**
Suppose you have a django app called "**blog**", that you want to use in "**www.cool.com**" and "**www.hot.com**" which would essentially be two different django projects, ( except for the "blog" app ofcourse ).

I want to this "blog" app to be like a service, which can be used by any 3rd party site.

**How would you do about doing it ?**

One of the solutions I thought was to host this "blog" app on another 3rd domain and handle the read/writes through an API but this would get quite cumbersome, I was thinking maybe there is a better way. Something I'm missing perhaps. Thank you.

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong but what I think I'm trying to do is use my **Django App as a service.**

A little more detail because I feel I may have not been entirely clear,
Excerpts from the comments below ->
*I want the codebase of the django app to remain in one place, but it should be usable by "n" number of projects.*
*can I add a django app from the cloud into my INSTALLED APPS of my django settings.py somehow?*

Comment: I can't say I understand your question.  It sounds like you have 2 sites, and one that is going to be a "web service site."  Whats the issue?  Are you saying that blog will be the gateway to your database?  And you just want to reuse the model?

Comment: I want to use this "blog" app for "n" number of sites, so I want to put it out as a service, which can be used by any 3rd party site

Comment: Only thing that will vary is the backing database?

Comment: Let me put it this way, there are some private apps and data, which belong to "cool.com" and "hot.com" and there's this public "blog" app, which I want to put out as a service

Comment: But I can have a back-end integration with these "cool.com" and "hot.com" django projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simplest solution will be:
[django muliple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) + lets say, PostgreSQL DB allowing crossdomain access.
Create router for your blog app and use any db you want.

UPD:

Somewhere

```
# class for routing db operations for  some blog myapp
class MyAppRouter(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models in
    the myapp application"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        "Allow any relation if a model in myapp is involved"
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'myapp' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Make sure the myapp app only appears on the 'other' db"
        if db == 'other':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'myapp'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return False
        return None
```

in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
     ...
     # Project DB
           }
# Blog DB
'blog': { 
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'admin',
    'HOST': '111.111.111.111',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

...
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.MyAppRouter', 'path.to.MasterSlaveRouter']
```

Comment: The problem is not so much the Database as the Code itself too...what suggestions for that?

Comment: Why would you want to use 2 different databases?

Comment: Write blog as usual, create router for it as suggested in [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example)... thats all. @Nix [quote]data for "www.cool.com" is stored in - X db
and the data for "www.hot.com" is stored in - Y db
and you want the data for the "blog" app to be stored in - Z db[/quote]

Comment: sorry Pill, I edited that part because I thought it was causing confusion

Comment: Hey Pill, thanks for posting the code really appreciate it, so you can tell me one thing, can I add a django app from the cloud into my INSTALLED APPS of my django settings.py somehow ?

Comment: Actually don't know, I was thinking about use case like: app is under version control, source code is included in both projects (so you can include blog app in installed_apps standard way) and when something changes you just synchronize them. There may be more clever way, but i don't now it ).

Answer (score 2):

The question is very, very hard to follow.

Two django sites which share a common app is trivial.  It's done all the time.

You're simply sharing the app code among the two sites.

Use subversion to keep the master copy of the `blog` app.

Checkout working copies for both sites.

> I want to this "blog" app to be like a service, which can be used by any 3rd party site.
>   I think I'm trying to do is use my Django App as a service.

This is trivial also.  Use [Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/) to create a RESTful web service around your blog app.

> handle the read/writes through an API but this would get quite cumbersome.

Not really.  RESTful web services are quite trivial.  Use `httplib` to be a client of a RESTful web service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, sorry but please do excuse my ignorance. I really have no clue what a subversion is, but from what I'm guessing I can have run the _blog_ app from one place, am I correct? So how do I subversion it ?

Comment: Also Piston looks awesome ! I'm surely going to try it out.

Comment: @Zach Wild: Please go to http://subversion.tigris.org/ and read about subversion.  Also, look at git, and mercurial.  http://git-scm.com/ http://mercurial.selenic.com/  This is how **everyone** assures that one application is used properly in two sites.